# Does YUI 3 have sliding panel similar to jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel

Does YUI 3 have a sliding panel construct similar to jquery mobile? I've been searching around and can't find one.

Thanks for any help.

Here's what I mean by a jquery mobile panel:

[image: Panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this handy HTML5 library for YUI 3

[Bottle Mobile UI Library](http://zordius.github.io/yui3-gallery/gallery-bottle/)

The page above includes a few handy examples (at the bottom of the page), including some overlays, which seem to be the equivalent of a jquery mobile panel.